# Attach invoice to shipment email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, invoice, attachment

In /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment.php I added the following lines in sendEmail() funtion:

```
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice(); 
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
$mailer->addAttachment($pdf, 'rechnung.pdf');
```

The file is correctly attached but the order items and invoice ID are missing.

For a test I added this in /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php :

```
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($this));
$mailer->addAttachment($pdf, 'rechnung.pdf');
```

This works 100% correctly.

Anybody see the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same request asked a while back. I used you question and your findings to solve our problem. I am posting in case someone else is in need of a solution.

I am using magento CE 1.9.1

**The leg work:**
"You never want to edit the core files always create an overwrite" and if you are really good create modules.

1. move `"app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php"` to `"app/code/**local**/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php"`
2. move `"/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment.php"` to
   `"/app/code/**local**/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment.php"`

**Coding:**

**Mailer.php**

1. add a protected variable before the first function declaration
   **protected $emailTemplate;**
2. Modify the Send function

.

```
*// comment out this line:*
        // $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
*// add these lines:*
        if ($this->emailTemplate)
            $emailTemplate = $this->emailTemplate;
        else
            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
```

3. Add a function at the bottom of the file before closing the class

.

```
public function addAttachment($template, Zend_Pdf $pdf, $filename){
 $file = $pdf->render();
        $attachment = $template->getMail()->createAttachment($file);
        if(!is_object($attachment)) return $this;
        $attachment->type = 'application/pdf';
        $attachment->filename = $filename;
        return $this;
 }
```

**Shipment.php**

1. below `$storeId = $order->getStore()->getId();` add:

.

```
/* get invoice PDF */
$invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
$pdfInvoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice');
$pdf = $pdfInvoice->getPdf($invoices);
```

2. below `$mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer')`;
   add:

.

```
$mailer->addAttachment($pdf,'invoice.pdf');
```

I found my answer in [Add PDF attachment to invoice email](http://www.ericpan.com/2013/02/14/add-pdf-attachment-to-invoice-email/#.Vs0QaPkrLbg)

Comment: This link would help: https://www.atwix.com/magento/pdf-invoice-email/