# How to attach packingslip to shipment email

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, pdf, transactional-mail, ce-1.9.2.4

I'm trying to add the packingslip pdf as attachment to the shipping email.

I saw this post [Attach invoice to shipment email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/attach-invoice-to-shipment-email?newreg=a5e4218785844752993f73ba52dcb072)
This adds the invoice, but not the packingslip.

The only thing I don't know is how to get the right shipment for creating the PDF. I keep getting the error render on non object.

I tried

```
$shipmenttt = $order->getShipmentsCollection()->getFirstItem();
$shipmentIncrementId = $shipmenttt->getIncrementId();   
$shipment = $this->load($shipmentIncrementId);
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_shipment')->getPdf(array($shipment));
```

and

```
$shipment = $this;
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_shipment')->getPdf(array($shipment));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out wat is was. and it is very simple:

all you need is:

```
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_shipment')->getPdf(array($this));
```

The addAttachment function from the link does not work. I changes it to:

```
public function addAttachment(Zend_Pdf $pdf, $filename)
{
    $file = $pdf->render();         
    $this->emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');       
    $attachment = $this->emailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment($file);
    if(!is_object($attachment)) return $this;
    $attachment->type = 'application/pdf';
    $attachment->filename = $filename;
    return $this;
}
```

Hope It helps someone else